# Is there an example of zero-sum game that has a Nash equilibrium which is not subgame perfect?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

As a refinement of  Nash equilibrium, it is known that not all Nash equilibria are [subgame perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgame_perfect_equilibrium). But it seems to me in zero-sum games of perfect information, Nash equilibrium coincides with subgame perfect equilibrium. Is it true for all zero-sum games?

Answer (score 3):

It is true that the set of Nash equilibrium and subgame-perfect equilibrium *outcomes* (distributions over terminal nodes) are equivalent for zero-sum games. However, the sets of equilibrium strategies need not be equivalent. Under subgame-perfect equilibrium, any off-equilibrium play is permitted.

Consider an extensive game $\Gamma$ and some subgame-pefect equilibrium strategies in which some subgame is reached with probability $0$. A Nash equilibrium strategy which induces the same outcome can be achieved by modifying some player's strategy to be non-credible in the subgame which is never reached along the equilibrium path.

Here is an example. Let player 1 move first. If 1 moves left, the game ends and payoffs are (5,-5). If player 1 moves right, player 2 moves. If player 2 moves left, payoffs are (3,-3) and if player moves right, payoffs are (2,-2).

Moving right is strictly dominated by left for player 1. The only NE and Subgame outcome is (5,-5) with probability 1. However, while (Left, Right) is the only subgame perfect strategy profile, (Left, Right) and (Left, Left) are Nash equilibrium strategies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight, especially the clarification between outcome and equilibrium strategy profile, which is of great help. But It still elude me how to show the outcome induced by Nash equilbrium and those are subgame perfect are equivalent in zero-sum game in general.